# Differences between `any?` and `exists?` in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In Ruby on Rails, there appear to be two methods to check whether a collection has any elements in it.

Namely, they are [ActiveRecord::FinderMethods’ exists?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.10/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) and [ActiveRecord::Relation’s any?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.10/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-any-3F). Running these in a generic query (`Foo.first.bars.exists?` and `Foo.first.bars.any?`) generated equivalent SQL. Is there any reason to use one over the other?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`#any` and `#exists?` are very different beasts but query similarly.

Mainly, `#any?` accepts a block — and with this block it retrieves the records in the relation, calls `#to_a`, calls the block, and then hits it with `Enumerable#any?`. Without a block, it's the equivalent to `!empty?` and counts the records of the relation.

`#exists?` *always* queries the database and never relies on preloaded records, and sets a LIMIT of 1. It's much more performant vs `#any?`. `#exists?` also accepts an options param as conditions to apply as you can see in the docs.

Comment: Why is `exists` much more performant when it never relies on preloaded records, and AFAICT otherwise results in the same query as a non-block `any`?

Comment: The last part is incorrect.  Using any? and exists? result in exactly the same SQL query and take the same amount of time - zero.

Answer (score 8):

The use of `ActiveRecord#any?` is reduced over `ActiveRecord#exists?`. With any? you can check, in the case of passing a block, if certain elements in that array matches the criteria. Similar to the [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) but don't confuse them.

The `ActiveRecord#any?` implements the `Enumerable#any?` inside the logic of its [definition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a419a4d9ade48e777166ff956dd7bb24e37b2181/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L276), by converting the Relation accessed to an array in case a block has been passed to it and yields and access the block parameters to implement in a "hand-made" way a "Ruby" `any?` method.

The handy else added is intended to return the negation of empty? applied to the Relation. That's why you can check in both ways if a model has or no records in it, like:

```
User.count # 0
User.any?  # false
# SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
User.exists? # false
# SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

You could also check in the "any?" way, if some record attribute has a specific value:

```
Foo.any? { |foo| foo.title == 'foo' } # SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
```

Or to save "efficiency" by using exists? and improve your query and lines of code:

```
Foo.exists?(title: 'foo') # SELECT  1 AS one FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."title" = ? LIMIT ?  [["title", "foo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

`ActiveRecord#exists?` offers many implementations and is intended to work in a SQL level, rather than `any?`, that anyways will convert the Relation what you're working with in an array if you don't pass a block.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've found any? to be problematic as it can give the wrong answer and then break subsequent queries, eg to get the first record of the has_many as rails seems to remember the (wrong) result returned by any?.  It's a shame because it reads nicely.

Answer (score 8):

The answers here are all based on very outdated versions. [This commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/02da8aea832485044fde1b94c021a66d37d54dec) from 2016 / ActiveRecord 5.1 changes `empty?`, which is called by `any?` when no block is passed, to call `exists?` when not preloaded.  So in vaguely-modern Rails, the only difference when no block is passed is a few extra method calls and negations, and ignoring preloaded results.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a practical issue: `exists?` forces a DB query while `any?` doesn't.

```rb
user = User.new
user.skills = [Skill.new]
user.skills.any?
# => true
user.skills.exists?
# => false
```

Consider having factories and a `before_create` hook:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills

  before_create :ensure_skills

  def ensure_skills
    # Don't want users without skills
    errors.add(:skills, :invalid) if !skills.exists?
  end
end


FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    skills { [association(:skill)] }
  end
end
```

`create(:user)` will fail, because at the time of `before_create` skills are not yet persisted. Using `.any?` will solve this.